# python just import fails but works with from

Tags: python

Why does this not work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import skimage
camera = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(skimage.data_dir, 'camera.png'))
#plt.show(io.imshow(camera))
```

But using `from skimage import io` does.  So this works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import skimage  # I still need to import skimage to get the data_dir
from skimage import io
camera = io.imread(os.path.join(skimage.data_dir, 'camera.png'))
#plt.show(io.imshow(camera))
```

I thought

```
import skimage
skimage.io."something"
```

Was equivalent to

```
from skimage import io
io."something"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought
>
> ```
> import skimage
> skimage.io."something"
> ```
>
> Was equivalent to
>
> ```
> from skimage import io
> io."something"
> ```

It's not.

```
import skimage
```

causes python to look for the skimage module. Maybe there's a `__init__.py` that sets up what becomes visible and what is done when you import that module.